# Use different background image in active jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, onclick

I am using jquery tabs as below in my page code and I want to css different background images to my tabs on click:

```
<div id=\"tabs\">

<ul>
    <li><div id="tab1" class="active"><a href=\"#tabs-1\">blah</a></div></li>
    <li><div id="tab2"><a href=\"#tabs-2\">blahhhhhh</a></div></li>
    <li><div id="tab3"><a href=\"#tabs-3\">blaj blah blah</a></div></li>
    <li><div id="tab4"><a href=\"#tabs-4\">bal blah</a></div></li>
    <li><div id="tab5"><a href=\"#tabs-5\">blahhh blah</a></div></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I use the click function to apply remove class

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#tabs").click(function(){
  if ($("#tab1, #tab2 ,#tab3, #tab4, #tab5").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#tab1, #tab2 ,#tab3, #tab4, #tab5").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $("#tab1, #tab2 ,#tab3, #tab4, #tab5").addClass("active");
  }
});

});
```

How can I have different class on each tab(1,2,3,4,5) id when clicking the tab menu?
With click function at #tabs it is toggling all tab classes.

Comment: where is the background styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to your #tabs element :

```
$('#tabs li').click(function() {
     $('#tabs li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addlass('active');

     // .index() will return 0, 1, 2, ....
     $('#tabs').addClass('class_'+ $(this).index());
}
```

In your CSS :

```
#tabs.class_1 { background: #FFFFFF; }
#tabs.class_2 { background: #AAAAAA; }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (e, ui) {
            ui.oldTab.find('div').removeClass('active');
            ui.newTab.find('div').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

then

```
#tab1.active a{
    background-color: red;
}
#tab2.active a{
    background-color: green;
}
#tab3.active a{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H652p/)

Answer (score 0):

Am i understanding this correct. You wan't each tab to have it's own css styling?

Sample on JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/optiguy/Nvy5K/

You could do something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tabs div").click(function(){
      $('#tabs div').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active'); //The div we clicked on
    });

});
```

Then use your css id to style each element for itself.

```
#tab1{background-image:sample1.jpg}
#tab2{background-image:sample2.jpg}
#tab3{background-image:sample3.jpg}
#tab4{background-image:sample4.jpg}
#tab5{background-image:sample5.jpg}
```

Comment: Sorry for answering with the same answer as below. I was a bit slow to answer, because I was on my break.

Answer (score 0):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/RRmLY/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><div id="tab1" class="active"><a href="#tabs-1">blah</a></div></li>
        <li><div id="tab2" ><a href="#tabs-2">blahhhhhh</a></div></li>
        <li><div id="tab3" ><a href="#tabs-3">blaj blah blah</a></div></li>
        <li><div id="tab4" ><a href="#tabs-4">bal blah</a></div></li>
        <li><div id="tab5" ><a href="#tabs-5">blahhh blah</a></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tab1.active{
    background-color: red;
}
#tab2.active{
    background-color: green;
}
#tab3.active{
    background-color: blue;
}
#tab4.active{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#tab5.active{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tabs div").click(function(){
    $("#tabs div").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
 });
});
```